# How to use jQuery fullScreen in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

I want to full screen, it works on the webpage, but it doesn't work in mobile (iPhone, iPad).

In iOs chrome or iOs safari both don't work. Not sure about Android.

```html
<img src='../../../images/icon/fullscreen.jpg' style="width:30px" onclick="$(document).fullScreen(true)"  href="javascript:;">
<img src='../../../images/icon/nofullscreen.jpg' style="width:30px" onclick="$(document).fullScreen(false)" href="javascript:;">
```

Comment: You MAY be able on Android but not on iOS

Comment: It's that jquery don't support mobile fullScreen?

Comment: No, iOS does not support fullscreen - see the dupe.